# Rails API - keeping an application controller method DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method in my Rails application controller that I call when I am creating a new Post. I have also created an API to create a new Post. However, it seems that I need to repeat the code for my application controller method in my API BaseController. Where is the best place to put the application controller method in my Rails app so that I do not have to repeat the code for the API? Is there a way that the API base controller can inherit from the ApplicationController?

**Rails app**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.text = foo_action(@post.text)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def foo_action(string)
    return string
  end
end
```

**Rails API**

```
class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.text = foo_action(@post.text)
    if @post.save
      respond_with(@post)
    end
  end
end

class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json

  def foo_action(string)
    return string
  end
end
```

Comment: hm, not sure about this but maybe you can put them in the application controller?

Comment: I currently have the method in the application controller, but unless I repeat the code in the base controller I will get a `NoMethodError (undefined method)`

Comment: looks like `foo_action` should be a part of the model. hard to say with you blanking out all the relevant information

Comment: @diasks2, well, like I said, not sure (cause mainly I'm sorta new), but maybe you can call it as a helper method? That way, you can call it in your Rails API without having to repeat it?

Comment: Thanks @phoet, that was the guidance I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @phoet's recommendation in the comments above, I moved the foo_action method to the Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def foo_action
    string = self.text
    return string
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.text = @post.foo_action
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
     render :new
    end
  end
end

class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   @post.text = @post.foo_action
   if @post.save
     respond_with(@post)
   end
 end
end
```